# Is unary minus equivalent to binop minus?

Tags: c, unary-operator, integer-promotion, binary-operators

My C compiler gave a warning when using unary minus on an `unsigned` value, so I fixed the warning by doing a subtraction from 0 instead.

Now I wonder if the current code is equivalent to the original one:

```c
uint32_t a, b; // assume b is initialized and non-zero

a =  -b   % b; // old code
a = (0-b) % b; // current code
```

My question is: for the same values of `b` will both lines of code yield the same result for `a`?

Comment: @juanchopanza, no not an exact duplicate because of possible integer promotion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, yes, unless on your platform `uint32_t` would be a narrow type. Then it would first be promoted to `int` and the negation would be made in that type.

Comment: In which case the end result would be the same :-)